# if clause nested in let inside a macro not working as expected

Tags: macros, common-lisp

Alright first of all this is my first question so I apologize for any bad practice and appreciate if you tell me I'm doing something wrong.

I am trying to write a macro to reduce repetitive code, which is create a package, system or code file in Common Lisp with a chapter number in its name. The following code is what I have and it works perfectly when :chapter-number is passed as a string, but goes wrong when it is passed as number:

```lisp
(defmacro with-open-chapter-file
  ((streamvar (component &key
                         (type "lisp")
                         (directory (sb-posix:getcwd))
                         chapter-number))
   (&body body))
  `(let ((chapter-number ,(if (numberp chapter-number) ; the problem is at this if clause.
                              (write-to-string chapter-number) ; My intention was to convert it to a string if it was a number or leave it as is otherwise.
                            chapter-number)))
     (with-open-file (,streamvar (make-pathname
                                  :name ,(if chapter-number ; the variable manipulated in the if clause is used in this expression
                                             (concatenate 'string "chapter-" chapter-number "-" (string component)) 
                                           component)
                                  :type ,type
                                  :defaults ,directory)
                                 :direction :output)
       ,body)))
```

When I run the following test:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(with-open-chapter-file (out ("pack" :chapter-number 10))
                   (format t "Hey!")))
```

I get the error:

```
The value
  10
is not of type
  SEQUENCE
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

And the backtrace:

```
  0: (LENGTH 10)
  1: (SB-KERNEL:%CONCATENATE-TO-STRING "chapter-" 10 "-" "pack")
  2: ((MACRO-FUNCTION WITH-OPEN-CHAPTER-FILE) (WITH-OPEN-CHAPTER-FILE (OUT ("pack" :CHAPTER-NUMBER 10)) (FORMAT T "Hey!")) #<unused argument>)
  3: ((FLET SB-IMPL::PERFORM-EXPANSION :IN MACROEXPAND-1) #<FUNCTION (MACRO-FUNCTION WITH-OPEN-CHAPTER-FILE) {2278173B}> NIL)
  4: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (MACROEXPAND-1 (QUOTE (WITH-OPEN-CHAPTER-FILE # #))) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  5: (EVAL (MACROEXPAND-1 (QUOTE (WITH-OPEN-CHAPTER-FILE # #))))
```

I would be extremely grateful if you guys could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical problem with macros is to understand that in general they deal with code: they receive code and produce code. Generally they don't know the value of variables, because the code has not been run yet.

For example imagine:

```
(let ((n 10))
  (with-open-chapter-file (out ("pack" :chapter-number n))
    (format t "Hey!")))
```

Now there is no general way in the macro to know what the value of `n` is. When the macro form gets expanded during compilation, it sees a `n` and nothing more.

Now when you have an actual number in the code, the macro sees that number as part of the source:

```
(with-open-chapter-file (out ("pack" :chapter-number 10)
  (format t "Hey!")))
```

Now we can ask us, if it would make sense for the macro to recognize the number during macro expansion and to compute something at macro expansion time? It's kind of an optimization and it might not be worth it. Now, the compiler might detect that it is a constant and could be converted at compile time...

Thus in your example it might be okay to at runtime convert the argument to a string, instead of doing it at macroexpansion time.

Now lets assume the code looks like this:

```
(defmacro with-open-chapter-file
          ((streamvar (component
                       &key
                       (type "lisp")
                       (directory "/foo/")
                       chapter-number))
           (&body body))
  (when (numberp chapter-number)
    (setf chapter-number (write-to-string chapter-number)))
  `(let ((component ,component)
         (type ,type)
         (directory ,directory)
         (chapter-number ,chapter-number))
     (when (numberp chapter-number)
       (setf chapter-number (write-to-string chapter-number)))
     (with-open-file
         (,streamvar (make-pathname
                      :name (if chapter-number
                                (format nil
                                        "chapter-~a-~a"
                                        chapter-number
                                        component)
                              component)
                      :type type
                      :defaults directory)
                     :direction :output)
       ,@body)))
```

Now we can do this:

a) with `n`

```
CL-USER 6 > (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(with-open-chapter-file (out ("pack" :chapter-number n))
                                                            (format t "Hey!"))))

(LET ((COMPONENT "pack") (TYPE "lisp") (DIRECTORY "/foo/") (CHAPTER-NUMBER N))
  (WHEN (NUMBERP CHAPTER-NUMBER) (SETF CHAPTER-NUMBER (WRITE-TO-STRING CHAPTER-NUMBER)))
  (WITH-OPEN-FILE (OUT
                   (MAKE-PATHNAME :NAME
                                  (IF CHAPTER-NUMBER
                                      (FORMAT NIL "chapter-~a-~a" CHAPTER-NUMBER COMPONENT)
                                    COMPONENT)
                                  :TYPE
                                  TYPE
                                  :DEFAULTS
                                  DIRECTORY)
                   :DIRECTION
                   :OUTPUT)
    FORMAT
    T
    "Hey!"))
```

and b) with `10`

```
CL-USER 7 > (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(with-open-chapter-file (out ("pack" :chapter-number 10))
                                                            (format t "Hey!"))))

(LET ((COMPONENT "pack") (TYPE "lisp") (DIRECTORY "/foo/") (CHAPTER-NUMBER "10"))
  (WHEN (NUMBERP CHAPTER-NUMBER) (SETF CHAPTER-NUMBER (WRITE-TO-STRING CHAPTER-NUMBER)))
  (WITH-OPEN-FILE (OUT
                   (MAKE-PATHNAME :NAME
                                  (IF CHAPTER-NUMBER
                                      (FORMAT NIL "chapter-~a-~a" CHAPTER-NUMBER COMPONENT)
                                    COMPONENT)
                                  :TYPE
                                  TYPE
                                  :DEFAULTS
                                  DIRECTORY)
                   :DIRECTION
                   :OUTPUT)
    FORMAT
    T
    "Hey!"))
```

But since `format` does a conversion anyway during printing, we can remove all that conversion logic...

```
(defmacro with-open-chapter-file
          ((streamvar (component
                       &key
                       (type "lisp")
                       (directory "/foo/")
                       chapter-number))
           (&body body))
  `(let ((component      ,component)
         (type           ,type)
         (directory      ,directory)
         (chapter-number ,chapter-number))
     (let ((name (if chapter-number
                     (format nil
                             "chapter-~a-~a"
                             chapter-number
                             component)
                   component)))
       (with-open-file (,streamvar (make-pathname
                                    :name     name
                                    :type     type
                                    :defaults directory)
                                   :direction :output)
         ,@body))))
```

Now you need to make sure that `component`, `type` ... are not unwanted runtime variables which then were visible from the body code...

Comment: That first sentence helped me a lot. I've never thought about not computing during macro expansion... thank you! And, just to make sure, the first let you included is just for aesthetic purposes, right? Could you apply the commas by hand like I did? (I know aesthetics is important and I think your way was better than mine, just wanna be sure about this.)

Comment: @GabrielSollero: one would actually use generated unique symbols in the LET. Sometimes it is useful to control the order of execution, then it might be useful to have a LET, because the execution is top -> down. Another thing where a LET can be helpful -> if you want to use the value from the passed expression multiple times, it might be useful to make sure that the value is actually only computed once.

Answer (score 4):

In the code:

```
  :name ,(if chapter-number ; the variable manipulated in the if clause is used in this expression
             (concatenate 'string "chapter-" chapter-number "-" (string component)) 
           component)
```

you're using the `chapter-number` parameter to the macro, not the variable that you bound with `let` in the expansion, because this code is after a comma.

You shouldn't be binding that variable in the expansion, you should just update the variable in the macro itself.

```
(defmacro with-open-chapter-file
  ((streamvar (component &key
                         (type "lisp") (directory (sb-posix:getcwd)) chapter-number))
   (&body body))
  (when (numberp chapter-number)
    (setq chapter-number (write-to-string chapter-number)))
  `(with-open-file (,streamvar (make-pathname
                                :name ,(if chapter-number
                                           (concatenate 'string "chapter-" chapter-number "-" (string component)) 
                                         component)
                                :type ,type
                                :defaults ,directory)
                                :direction :output)
     ,@body))
```

Another solution that doesn't require testing the type of `chapter-number` is to change the code that uses `concatenate` to use `format`:

```
(if chapter-number
    (format nil "chapter-%A-%A" chapter-number component)
    component)
```

An unrelated mistake is that you should use `,@body` to substitute the body, since it's a list that must be spliced into the expression.